# Resolve deferred only after multiple ajax calls has returned all data - offset / take

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am making a call to a web service that returns a collection of books, with each request containing a 'MoreItems' flag to indicate if there is more data for the request to return. This is because the web service returns data in a paged fashion limited to 100, so the client must request with an offset value.

e.g:

```
   var getBooksFromWebserver = function (param) {
    return {
        uri: 'https://webservice.com/Books/GetBooks?authorId=' + param.author+ '&offset=param.offset&get=param.get',
        method: 'GET',
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    }
};

 Data: {
    Books : [],
    MoreData: true
    }
```

The call to getBooksFromWebserver is called like this:

```
module.exports.GetBooks = function (data) {

    rp(getBooksFromWebserver(data), function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {

           } 
            response.setEncoding(appLibconfig.encoding);
            writer.transformAndWrite(data, body);

    });

};
```

The issue I am having is implementing a Deferred to wait until MoreData returns false (so I know all data is retrieved) before proceeding to  writer.transformAndWrite(data, body);

So, it needs to iterate the getBooksFromWebserver call, cache the response locally to retain each response, then when MoreData is false, write the data and and clear the cache.

I have tried various techniques but am struggling to implement a pattern that works, any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the data being returned in a pagination manner like one by one or all together ?

Comment: Data is returned in batches of 100, so i need to make calls like; get=100; offset=0, then get=100; offset=100, unti MoreData returns false in response

Comment: Then is simple check after every data return `if(body.MoreData == true)` then dont resolve call it again, and when condition fails resolve it.

Comment: Yes that's the approach I need; it's just the actual method to implement it into the above code example I am unsure of

Comment: then please provide full related code for me to help.

Comment: thanks, the above is basically where I am up to, it's how to proceed and have getBooksFromWebserver call on loop until body.MoreData == false

Answer (score 0):

The code might help -

```
module.exports.GetBooks = function (data) {
    var allData = [];
    function getBooks() {
        rp(getBooksFromWebserver(data), function(err, response, body) {
            if (body && body.MoreData == true) {
                allData = allData.concat(body); //assuming the data retured in array of objects
                getBooks(); //calling again change data for next pagination
            }
            else {
                response.setEncoding(appLibconfig.encoding);
                writer.transformAndWrite(data, allData);
            }
        });
    }
};
```